# Use same dataset in different method

Tags: c#, dataset

In one method I fill data into dataset and I want to use the same dataset with data in my other method, but I don't want to declare the dataset as static so how is that possible?

```
static DataSet dset = new DataSet();
```

Comment: We need more information. Are the methods static? Are they in the same class? How do you call them? Why don't you want to declare a static field?

Comment: Other method in same class in different class? Please explain.

Comment: yes, they are in the same class ,i have e search process and every time user clicks the button gets the data and fills it in the dataset and if i declare the dataset static i can't change the data in it every time.

Comment: Just to make it explicit: absolutely **do not** make that static

Comment: My psychic powers suggest that this is a web question, and that static was an attempt to persist values between postbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you you declare this data set in class scope? That way both methods will have access to that instance.

Comment: yes they will have access to the instance but not the data in it.

Comment: i am not sure if i understand u correctly. Can you explain why the second method w
ont have access to data? Are you talking about am asp .net project?

Comment: yes, i tried and declared it in class scope and filled it in one method and when i wanted to bind that dataset with gridview in another method there was no data in dataset .

Comment: If you are developing a web app, you can try to persist the data (as sq33G suggested) by using Session, so that the value will be available. You can put this together with the solution given by hawkke to solve your problem. ie; If the data is available in Session don't hit DB.

Answer (score 1):

```
public DataSet GetData()
{
    DataSet ds;
    // code to fetch data here
    return ds;
}

public void MethodThatUsesDataSet(DataSet ds)
{
    // use dataset here
}

// call it like this:
MethodThatUsesDataSet(GetData());
```

Comment: every time i call that method goes and gets data from DB and that incur network overhead.